# Why is the buttons only clickable on the top half?

Tags: html, css

You can go to my test page here: https://socialstamp.me.uk/new/testpage.php

The buttons to your left (under balance), only the top half of them can be clicked, bottom half doesn't work/click. I've checked the CSS styling file and can't find anything, I've tried many solutions but nothing works.

Button code:

```
             <ul>
             <li id="l2"><a href="dashboard.php"></a></li>
             <li id="l3"><a href="trackingPanel.php"></a></li>
             <li id="l4"><a href="topup.php"></a></li>
             <li id="l5"><a href="contactform.php"></a></li>
             <li id="l6"><a href="accountSettings.php"></a></li>
             <li id="l7"><a href="apiHelp.php"></a></li>
             <li id="l8"><a href="referrals.php"></a></li>  
             </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#dashContainer .col-md-2 li {
display:block; 
height: 40px;
margin-bottom: 1px;
margin-left: 15px;
margin-right: 0;
}

#l2 {
   background-image: url('../img/menu/btn3.jpg');
}
#l2:hover {

background-image: url('../img/menu/btn3h.jpg');
}
#l2:active {

background-image: url('../img/menu/btn3h.jpg');
}

And so on for several buttons...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is `<li>` tags have 41px height but `<a>` tags doesn't have any height except font-size. By default `<a>` tags displayed `inline` so your clickable area just taking up space as `<a>` tags font size. There are too many ways to fix it.

**First option :** ( original answer )

By giving height and width to `<a>` tags as container:

```
 #dashContainer .col-md-2 li a {
    display:block;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
 }
```

**Second option :**

By adjusting `<a>` padding. No need give height to `li` tags **if it is not important for UI**.

```
#dashContainer .col-md-2 li {
   display:block; 
   /* height: 40px; */
   margin-bottom: 1px;
   margin-left: 15px;
   margin-right: 0;
}
#dashContainer .col-md-2 li a {
   padding:20px 0px;
}
```

**Third option :**

By giving height to `<a>` tags.

```
#dashContainer .col-md-2 li {
   display:block; 
   /* height: 40px; */
   margin-bottom: 1px;
   margin-left: 15px;
   margin-right: 0;
}
#dashContainer .col-md-2 li a {
   display:block;
   height:40px;
   line-height:40px; // for text vertical align
   width:100%;
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation and more code that shows how this helps the OP.

Comment: [Code-only answers are discouraged.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272)

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised the buttons work at all. While you define the size of the `<li>`, there is nothing defining the `<a>` and so in theory it should be of size 0, and therefore unclickable.

Make sure to apply your widths and heights to the link itself!

Comment: Somewhere there's a padding-top: 11px and the `<a>` is being stuffed in that, so it's 11px high at the top of the `<li>`.

Comment: @blm Yes, there is, I can see it in the style.css - What would I edit/change?

Comment: Sizing your a tags with padding can be a very good way of doing just that, or just add width and height to the anchors. Whatever floats your boat.

Comment: @Tanner_Gram That worked, thank you! I added height/width/display:block - but please see the page again. Now the top button (Buy a Service) seems to be repeating itself slightly.

Answer (score 0):

this issue can be resolved if you will add a css height 41px in links.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem. It's also recommended that you don't post an answer if it's just a guess. A good answer will have a plausible reason for why it could solve the OP's issue.